# XCode 12: 'SessionDelegate' has different definitions in different modules

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire, kingfisher, xcode12

**Edit:**
This problem occurs after XCode 12 Beta5. Xcode doesn't allow different modules to define same names (Probably for public classes & protocols). Alamofire and Kingfisher appears to define SessionDelegate at the same time. I'm still trying to find a solution..

I'm implementing iOS 14 Widgets in our application. I have started working with **XCode 12 Beta 2** and everthing was compiling fine. When I have updated XCode to **XCode 12 Beta 6**, I faced with following error:

> 'SessionDelegate' has different definitions in different modules;
> first difference is definition in module 'Kingfisher.Swift' found end
> of class

I'm also attaching the screenshot of the file with error.

[image]

Is there any way to edit header files to have different names for SessionDelegate for Alamofire or Kingfisher? Is there any workaround to overcome this issue?

Here are things I have tried so far:

- I have updated both Alamofire and Kingfisher to latest version
- I have cleaned **Podfile.lock** and all pods as well as **Derived Data**
- I tried to compile with **Legacy Build System**

Comment: I have edited my question accordingly @matt

Comment: You would need to complain to the pod authors. Objective C has no namespaces, so you are supposed to give your types unique names using prefixing. They didn’t. That was dumb but there’s nothing _you_ can do about it. Unless you want to just change their code, which is not a very robust approach because an update will wipe out your changes.

Comment: From the code posted, it's apparent Kingfisher tried to provide a mangled Swift name which does provide the namespace. Perhaps there's an issue with this approach in Xcode 12. @FeridunErbaş you should file a bug with Kingfisher about this to see if they can fix it. In the meantime you can fork the library and do your own rename.

Comment: @JonShier Alamofire and Kingfisher are conflicting actually. I will file a bug to both of them

Comment: That bug will be closed for Alamofire, since there's nothing for us to do there. Swift has namespacing, so there's no need for the type prefix that Obj-C needs.

Comment: The issue happens if one of the frameworks is an ObjC framework. 

If you have swift frameworks only - everything works fine.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson Plus, my _second_ comment (now the first), made after the question was improved, is in fact the correct answer. So really there is nothing wrong about how the conversation went.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

At this moment (Xcode 12.0 or Xcode 12.2b2), the only possible solution is to rename the Objective-C interface and avoid conflicts. This could be done by one of:

- Rename conflicting class entirely, update all places where it's used (e.g. replace **SessionDelegate** by **KingfisherSessionDelegate**)
- Add `@objc(...)` attribute to a Swift class, which will update the Obj-C interface in a generated `...-Swift.h` file and avoid the names conflict.

```swift
//  SessionDelegate.swift
@objc(KFSessionDelegate)
class SessionDelegate: NSObject { ... }
```

```
//  Kingfisher-Swift.h
@interface KFSessionDelegate : NSObject
...
@end
```

This solution is already included in the Kingfisher [5.15.4 release](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/releases/tag/5.15.4) and could be applied to any other libraries and your own frameworks.

Also, the thread on Apple forums: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/658012

Answer (score 31):

You can try SWIFT_INSTALL_OBJC_HEADER = NO,  it works for me

[image]

Comment: Can you make your answer a little bid more specific? From where exactly should we change this flag?

Comment: Go to Project, Build Settings, select All tab, search for SWIFT_INSTALL_OBJC_HEADER, and change its value to NO. 
Anyway, it's not working.

Comment: This worked for me, you just do this step under the framework setting not in your project target

Comment: thank you , this worked for me under framework setting , good hint @PankajSonava

Comment: @PankajSonava hey just wondering how do i manage to do this under the framework setting instead of in the project target? because i can't get this solved

Comment: Hey @llehcram follow these steps :-  1. Click on Pods from your Xcode Project Navigator. 2. There are you can see the list of framework you attached with project.  3. Then you select the framework which show this error. 4. Under this framework setting you need to do this steps

Comment: This doesnt work for me.  Am using Swift Packages, perhaps that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

for me worked when I update the 'SWIFT_INSTALL_OBJC_HEADER' key in podfile

```
post_install do |installer|             
 installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target| 
   target.build_configurations.each do |config|                          
     if target.name == 'Alamofire'         
         target.build_configurations.each do |config|  
           config.build_settings['SWIFT_INSTALL_OBJC_HEADER'] = 'No'                 
           end                                                        
         end                                                          
       end                                                            
     end                                                              
   end
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying that you have multiple classes with the same name **SessionDelegate** in different modules. **This error is related to Xcode 12.**

For now, a quick solution is to install the module with CocoaPods (if you're using Carthage) and if needed, rename the *SessionDelegate* interface.

Answer (score 1):

If you guys need a temporary solution, here is how for Cocoapods users:

1. Clone the Kingfisher library to the same folder level with your project. You can get it from [Github](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)
2. Open **Kingfisher.xcworkspace** in XCode and rename SessionDelegate.swift file under Sources/Netowking to KingFisherSessionDelegate and change the class name as well accordingly.
3. Rename the usages of SessionDelegate to KingfisherSessionDelegate which is only available in Sources/Networking/ImageDownloader.swift as of Kingfisher version 5.15.0
4. Add local path in your **Podfile**

   pod 'Kingfisher', :path => '../Kingfisher'

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same issue, sam's solution worked for me but with one change. There are 2 pods with the same definition so i changed the value of SWIFT_INSTALL_OBJC_HEADER to NO for both the pods. After doing it i was getting import error in one of the pod. So then i changed SWIFT_INSTALL_OBJC_HEADER to YES for that particular pod which was having the import error and kept the other pods SWIFT_INSTALL_OBJC_HEADER to NO. This worked for me.

[image: This pod was giving import error]

[image]