# Xcode 12: SDWebImageManager' has different definitions in different modules;

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode12

As I run the app it is giving compile time error on this class of SDWebImage

@property (weak, nonatomic) id  delegate;

Error: SDWebImageManager' has different definitions in different modules; first difference is defined here found default 'assign' property attribute

Comment: Refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63614048/xcode-12-sessiondelegate-has-different-definitions-in-different-modules

Comment: You can apply same procedure for SDWebImageManager instead of Kingfisher from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63954707/5828331

Comment: @FeridunErbaş already tried that but still having issue.