# How to fix 'FXPageControlDelegate' has different definitions in different modules swift compiler error in Xcode 12.1?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Recently upgraded to Xcode 12.1, and when I try to build my project, I got this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3OkR.png).

> 'FXPageControlDelegate' has different definitions in different modules; first difference is defined here found return type is 'UIImage * _Nonnull'

> 'FXPageControl' has different definitions in different modules; first difference is defined here found property name 'dotShape'

I did some research and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63614048/xcode-12-sessiondelegate-has-different-definitions-in-different-modules/63933373?noredirect=1#comment113914070_63933373), but when I tried to look for `SWIFT_INSTALL_OBJC_HEADER = NO` option in the framework's Build Settings tab, I can't seem to find it. My question is, is there anyway to solve this problem without renaming the framework's class that has this issue?